# Actionscript click on background/stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I am trying this but it doesn't work:

```
_root.onPress = function(){
..
}
```

I want to click wherever I want, not only in object, is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "stage" doesn't trigger `onPress`-events in AS2 (as it assumes there is nothing to press - like a button or MovieClip or whatever). But you can still capture `onMouseDown` instead like:

```
_root.onMouseDown = function(){
    trace('hello');
};
```